# How to fetch image from firestore on flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I tried to fetch images and topic and descriptions for each "doc id ", Successfully fetch topic and description but when I tried to fetch image then shows "URL undefined" .For this code I used model class also.And in there I decleard "URL" and in the UI code I called that in an" Imagenetwrok widget".

code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../articlesModel.dart';

class ViewArticlesScreens extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewArticlesScreens({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ViewArticlesScreens> createState() => _ViewArticlesScreensState();
}

class _ViewArticlesScreensState extends State<ViewArticlesScreens> {
  @override
  Future<List<Articles>> fetchRecords() async {
    var records = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('articles').get();
    return mapRecords(records);
  }

  List<Articles> mapRecords(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> records) {
    var _list = records.docs
        .map(
          (article) => Articles(
            id: article.id,
            topic: article['topic'],
            description: article['description'],
            url: article['url'],
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    return _list;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              //chip words
              children: <Widget>[
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                SizedBox(
                    width: width * 0.94,
                    height: height * 0.30,
                    child: FutureBuilder<List<Articles>>(
                        future: fetchRecords(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                          } else {
                            List<Articles> data = snapshot.data ?? [];

                            return ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: data.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return (ListTile(
                                    leading: Image.network(
                                      url,
                                      height: 30,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    ),
                                    title: Text(data[index].topic),
                                    subtitle: Text(data[index].description),
                                    tileColor: Colors.red,
                                  ));
                                });
                          }
                        }))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

model class

```
import 'dart:convert';

Articles articlesFromJson(String str) => Articles.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String articlesToJson(Articles data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Articles {
  Articles({
    required this.id,
    required this.url,
    required this.topic,
    required this.description,
  });
  String id;
  String topic;
  String description;
  String url;

  factory Articles.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Articles(
        id: json["id"] ?? "",
        topic: json["topic"] ?? "",
        description: json["description"] ?? "",
        url: json["url"] ?? "",
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "topic": topic,
        "description": description,
        "url": url,
      };
}
```

Comment: can you include `snapshot.data` response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just set `url` instead of `data[index].url`

here try this :

```
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return (ListTile(
                                leading: Image.network(
                                  data[index].url,
                                  height: 30,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                                title: Text(data[index].topic),
                                subtitle: Text(data[index].description),
                                tileColor: Colors.red,
                              ));
                            });
                      }
```